# Looking for a simpler alternative to a recursive query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

The actual query is more involved, but the problem I'm facing can be distilled to this:

*A query to filter a rowset of monotonically increasing integers so that - **in the final result set, row(n+1).value >= row(n).value + 5**.*

For the actual problem I need to solve, the rowset count is in the 1000s.

A few examples to clarify:

- if rows are: 1,2,3,4,5 : then query should return: 1
- if rows are: 1,5,7,10,11,12,13 : then query should return: 1,7,12
- if rows are: 6,8,11,16,20,23: then query should return: 6,11,16,23
- if rows are: 6,8,12,16,20,23: then query should return: 6,12,20

I've managed to get the required results with the following query, but it seems overly complicated. Uncomment the different "..with t(k).." to try them out.

I'm looking for any simplifications or alternative approaches to get the same results.

```
    with recursive r(n, pri) as (
    with t(k) as (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))   -- the data we want to filter
    -- with t(k) as (values (1),(5),(7),(10),(11),(12),(13))
    -- with t(k) as (values (6),(8),(11),(16),(20),(23))
    -- with t(k) as (values (6),(8),(12),(16),(20),(23))
    select min(k), 1::bigint from t             -- bootstrap for recursive processing. 1 here represents rank().
    UNION
    select k, (rank() over(order by k)) rr      -- rank() is required just to filter out the rows we dont want from the final result set, and no other reason
    from r, t 
    where t.k >= r.n+5 and r.pri = 1            -- capture the rows we want, AND unfortunately a bunch of rows we dont want 
)
select n from r where pri = 1;                  -- filter out the rows we dont want
```

Comment: Dont you mean: `row(n-2) <= row(n) -5` ? for example: why is the `7` in the 2nd example in the output. Because of the `1` in 1st postion?

Comment: Okay, I understand now; the gap condition is based on the *result* set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- The data:
CREATE TABLE rowseq(val INTEGER NOT NULL) ;
INSERT INTO rowseq(val ) values
    -- (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
         (1), (5), (7), (10), (11), (12), (13)
    --(6),(8),(11),(16),(20),(23)
    --(6),(8),(12),(16),(20),(23)
        ;

        -- need this view, because a recursive CTE cannot be based on a CTE
        -- [we could also duplicate the row_number() in both legs of the recursive CTE]
CREATE TEMP VIEW qqq AS
        SELECT val, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY val) AS rn
        FROM rowseq
        ;

WITH RECURSIVE rrr AS (
        SELECT qqq.val, qqq.rn
        FROM qqq
        WHERE qqq.rn = 1
UNION
        SELECT q1.val, q1.rn
        FROM rrr
        JOIN qqq q1 ON q1.rn > rrr.rn AND q1.val >= rrr.val+5 -- The "Gap" condition
                AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM  qqq nx                  -- But it must be the FISRT match
                        WHERE nx.rn > rrr.rn AND nx.val >= rrr.val+5    -- same condition
                        AND nx.rn < q1.rn                               -- but NO earlier match
                        )
        )
-- prove it to the world!
SELECT *
FROM rrr
        ;
```

Comment: Thx ! Any pro's of this implementation versus my original ? Guess the tradeoff is 'rank() over' vs 'not exist (select..'

Comment: IMHO the `min(k)` in the *terminal* part of your recursive query will always select the same value, indepently of the recursive leg.

Answer (score 0):

What about using plpgsql?

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(k) as (
  values 
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
    --(1),(5),(7),(10),(11),(12),(13)
    --(6),(8),(11),(16),(20),(23)
    --(6),(8),(12),(16),(20),(23)
);

create or replace function foo(in n int, out k int) returns setof int as $$
declare
  r t;
  rp t;
begin
  rp := null;
  for r in (select * from t) loop
    if (rp is null) or (r.k >= rp.k + n) then
      rp := r;
      k := r.k;
      return next;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return;
end; $$ immutable language plpgsql;

select * from foo(5);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in my original question that I'm looking for a non cursor / for-loop approach. This (for loop) is what I currently have. I'm looking for a decent pure sql option so I can compare the relative performance of the two.

Comment: Although, I like your cursor impl. better than the one I have, so I'll use it until I find a better sql impl. Thx !

Comment: @sr33 IMO you should to make decision between head-braking (but, probably, more efficiency) pure SQL and more logically approach using cursors. Actually, the right way is to tune the data  model to avoid such problems at all. IMO.